# Como puedo optimizar dos bucles en python?

Tags: python, bucle-for, condiciones, optimización

Estoy desarrollando un simulador para un proyecto usando python. Una parte del codigo nuevo que he integrado hace que el tiempo que tarda en hacer la simulacion tarde una barbaridad y me gustaria saber si puedo optimizarlo antes de buscar alternativas. No puedo poner el codigo real, pero se asemaja a esto:

las listas las crea otra parte de del simulador, al igual que la variable t. Son todo numeros.

```
l1=[.....]
l2=[....]
l3=[.....]
l4=[....]
t=..

for T_1 in range(t, t+2*60): 
    if (T_1 not in l1) and (T_1 not in l2) :
        for T_2 in range(t+5, t+40):
            if  (T_2 not in l3) and (T_2 not in l4):
                   "FUNCION que utiliza t como variable de entrada si cumple las condiciones anteriores"
            else:
                t=+1
                break
    else:
        t=+1
```

La intencion de este codigo es que tengo que ver si cada elemento dentro de un intervalo (que se construye a partir de t) se encuentra dentro de unas listas y si no es asi, el valor de t entra dentro de una funcion. Si por el contrario, algun elemento del intervalo esta en las listas, quiero que t avance al valor siguiente y vuelva a pasar por todo el proceso hasta que encuentre un valor que no esta en las listas.

por ejemplo si t=30, quiero ver si los numeros en el intervalo [30,180] no estan dentro de dos listas, si es el caso, pasar al intervalo siguiente [35,70] y ver si tampoco ningun elemento de este intervalo esta en otras dos listas. Si no se cumplen alguna de las condiciones, quiero que t pase a valer 31 y que se repita el proceso.

La verdad es que ando un poco perdido, no he intentado todavia nada, salvo el eliminar los bucles y flexibilizar las condiciones del simulador. Cualquier ayuda se agradece. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Aunque no tiene que ver con la parte del bucle que quieres optimizar, me parece que `t=+1` no es lo que estás buscando hacer, sino (tal vez): `t+=1`. Saludos

Comment: Si la función es idempotente (siempre el mismo resultado para los mismos argumentos) y la estas llamando una y otra vez con los mismos valores, puedes aplicar memoización sin necesidad de cambiar tu código. Revisa [Que es memoización y como se usa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/398370/qu%c3%a9-es-memoizaci%c3%b3n-y-c%c3%b3mo-se-usa)

Comment: Gracias por las aclaraciones, sobre el signo, lo voy a cambiar. No es idempotente la funcion.

Comment: ¿Estas consciente de que cambiar `t` dentro del `for` sólo afecta al `for T_2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mirar si un dato está o no en una lista (con expresiones como `T_2 not in l3` y similares) es una operación costosa, sobre todo en listas largas.

En ese caso tendrías una increíble ganancia de velocidad si en vez de listas usaras conjuntos, aunque tal vez no sea aplicable a tu caso (depende del tipo de los valores que tengas en las listas). Sin más detalles no es posible saberlo. En todo caso, si pudieras usar conjuntos algo como lo siguiente sería mucho más eficiente:

```
l1=[.....]
l2=[....]
l3=[.....]
l4=[....]
t=..

conjunto1_2 = set(l1) | set(l2)  # Union de conjuntos
conjunto3_4 = set(l3) | set(l4)  # Union de conjuntos

for T_1 in range(t, t+2*60): 
    if T_1 not in conjunto1_2:
        for T_2 in range(t+5, t+40):
            if  T_2 not in conjunto3_4:
                   "FUNCION que utiliza t como variable de entrada si cumple las condiciones anteriores"
            else:
                t+=1
                break
    else:
        t+=1
```

## Actualización

Tras la edición de la pregunta por parte del OP entiendo que de lo que se trata es de:

1. Partir de un valor de `t`
2. Detectar si cualquiera de los valores en el rango [t, t+2*60) están en la lista l1 ó l2, **o bien** cualquiera de los valores en el rango [t+5, t+40) están en la lista l3 ó l4.
3. Si se cumple la condición 2, incrementar `t` y repetir
4. Cuando se encuentra un valor de `t` que no cumpla 2, entonces invocar cierta función con el parámetro `t`  (y entiendo que en ese caso se invoca una sola vez, no se sigue probando con más valores de `t`).

Si traducimos esto a conjuntos tendríamos (usando ∩ para la intersección de conjuntos y ∪ para la unión de conjuntos):

1. Inicializar `t`,
2. Detectar si `rango1 ∩ (l1 ∪ l2)` es distinto de vacío o si `rango2 ∩ (l3 ∪ l4)` es distinto de vacío, siendo rango1 = conjunto que contiene el intervalo [t, t+2*20); rango2 = conjunto que contiene el intervalo[t+5, t+40)
3. Si se cumple la condición 2, incrementar `t` y repetir
4. Hasta que la condición no se cumpla, en cuyo caso se ha encontrado el valor de `t` para llamar a la función.

Se trata por tanto de un bucle `while` en el que se incrementa `t` y la condición es la expresada en el punto 2.

La traducción a Python sería por tanto la siguiente (`|` es la unión de conjuntos y `&` es la intersección):

```
l1=[.....]
l2=[....]
l3=[.....]
l4=[....]

# Para eficiencia, convertimos a conjuntos las listas, antes de entrar al bucle
# para no tener que hacer esa conversión en cada iteración, y obtengo ya
# las uniones de las listas l1 y l2 por un lado, y l3, l4 por el otro.

l1Ul2 = set(l1) | set(l2)
l3Ul4 = set(l3) | set(l4)

# Bucle
t = ...
while (set(range(t, t+2*60)) & l1Ul2) or (set(range(t+5, t+40)) & l3Ul4):
  t+=1

# Al salir del bucle hemos encontrado el valor de t deseado
FUNCION_A_LLAMAR(t)
```

En la condición del `while` me valgo del hecho de que un conjunto no vacío se evalúa como `True` en un contexto booleano. Por tanto `(set(range(t, t+2*60)) & l1Ul2)` es `True` si la intersección es no vacía.

Comment: gracias, voy a intenterlo con los conjuntos. creo que aplica a mi caso.

Comment: De todas formas, fijándome mejor, no sé qué se pretende con el `t+=1`. Eso no afecta para nada al rango sobre el que iterarán T_1 y T_2 (que depende sólo del valor que se asignó en `t=..`). Solo afectaría, eso sí, a lo que se le pasa a esa "funcion que utiliza t como variable de entrada"

Comment: t es un timestamp, la idea era que cada vez que no se cumpla una de las condiciones, el valor de t pase al timestamp siguiente, sumandole uno al valor original, y vuelva a pasar por los bucles. Tal vez me haya confundido en el planteamiento

Comment: Tengo la intuición de que lo que buscas necesitaría convertir los rangos también a conjuntos y trabajar con intersecciones o diferencias de conjuntos. Pero no entiendo aún qué necesitas. Prueba a expresarlo con un ejemplo en que muestres valores de `l1`, `l2`, etc (puedes editar la pregunta para añadir esa información)

Comment: Si no entiendo mal creo que lo que quiere es (números en rango t,t+2*60 pero no en conjunto1_2) intersección (números en rango t+5,t+40 pero no en conjunto3_4). Aunque es solo una suposición, así que mejor confirmarlo...

Comment: @abulafia he intentado aclarar el texto original. las listas lo que marcan son los instantes donde se producen ciertos eventos, t es el final o el comienzo de otro evento nuevo.  El intervalo de tiempo que dura dicho evento tampoco puede estar en las listas, de ahi los rangos con el for. Si hay coincidencia, mi instante t no me vale y tengo que buscar el mas proximo. Gracias a todos por las respuestas!!!

Comment: @JoseCle Creo que entendí. He editado la respuesta con una ampliación. Mira a ver si es eso lo que tratabas de expresar (que no es por cierto lo que hacía el código que habías dado de muestra)

Comment: @abulafia enorme, mil gracias, era justo eso

Answer (score 0):

dando por hecho que hardware y volumen datos se corresponden en cuanto a capacidad de procesado, ¿has probado a guardar los datos en una estructura de tablas y a partir de ahí trabajarlos?

No siempre la opción más "correcta", es la más adecuada.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, tienes algun ejemplo? No estoy seguro de saber a qué te refieres

Comment: Lo que yo te propongo es, en vez de almacenar los datos en listas, tuplas, etc... guardarlos en tabla.

una tabla por cada conjunto.
De esa forma, podrías buscar el que necesites con una SQL simple. 
Si además necesitas incrementar la variable, el campo de la columna correspondiente lo estableces en un auto_increment y solo la accion de añadir registro lo tendrás.