# cache en python

Tags: python, cache

tengo una tarea de cache en python, me pidieron hacer un programa que calcule la suma de potencias de un numero, ya logre eso, pero en uno de los incisos de la pregunta dice: Crear una cache virtual que almacene la información de los datos llamados y ejecutar la función para N = 5, 10, 100, 500, 1000, 5, 10, 100, 500, 1000.
Entiendo que utiliza el cache como una biblioteca que almacena, he visto por tutoriales que colocan

```
cache={}
cache.keys
```

, pero no entiendo como implementarlo en mi codigo:

```
def suma_potencias (numero_de_sumas):
    i = 1
    potencia=1
    suma=0
    while i <= numero_de_sumas:
        potencia= pow(i,i)
        suma= potencia +suma
        i=i+1
    return suma
```

deseo entender como introducir el cache en mi código, es que tengo que modificar la función por dentro?
gracias

Comment: Una caché en este caso no sería más que un almacén que guarde qué valores ya han sido computados por la función, para evitar perder tiempo computándolos de nuevo. Un diccionario podría usar como clave el parámetro que le has pasado a la función, y como valor el resultado que ésta retorna. Así, antes de computar de nuevo, miras si `numero_de_sumas` está ya en el diccionario y en ese caso retornas directamente su valor. Si no, lo computas, lo añades, y lo retornas. El problema aquí es dónde guardar ese diccionario.

Comment: No sé qué conocimientos tienes de python, por lo que la solución depende de eso. Una forma sencilla es usar una variable global. Una forma más sofisticada que evita las variables globales sería usar una _closure_. Una forma bastante rara sería usar atributos de funciones. También podrías implementar un decorador, o usar uno que ya te da Python como parte de `functools` que hace precisamente esto (implementar una cache)

Comment: Si crees que merezca la pena puedo escribir una respuesta mostrando todas estas alternativas

Comment: @abulafia. Ya está respondida "¿Qué es memoización?"

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Qué es memoización y cómo se usa?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/398370/qu%c3%a9-es-memoizaci%c3%b3n-y-c%c3%b3mo-se-usa)

Comment: @CandidMoe Ah, pues sí, excelente respuesta (y ya te había dado el +1 en su día :-)

Comment: @abulafia  muchas gracias por su ayuda la verdad es que soy principiante en Python pero el curso que estoy llevando en la universidad esta yendo a la velocidad de la luz, :') agradezco su ayuda, leeré mas a fondo

Answer (score 1):

> Es una pregunta bastante vieja pero quizás le sirva a otros colegas.

Existe una librería incluida en python (todas las versiones pero hablaré solo de la version 3.x) que permite implementar caché muy sencillo, la librería se llama **functools** y voy a utilizarla en el código de la pregunta:

```
    from functools import lru_cache

    @lru_cache() #decorador que se encargara almacenar en cache tu funcion
    def suma_potencias (numero_de_sumas):
        i = 1
        potencia=1
        suma=0
        while i <= numero_de_sumas:
            potencia= pow(i,i)
            suma= potencia +suma
            i=i+1
        return suma

    print (suma_potencias.cache.info()) #aqui podras observar cuantas veces se esta utilizando el cache

    suma_potencias.cache.clean() #con esta purgarias la cache
```

Se puede usar la función `time` para poder hacer las pruebas de tiempo del código.

Comment: Para que no sea problema la indentación, cuando insertas código, agrega triples acentos graves (```) una línea antes y una después de tal código, en lugar de cuatro espacios al inicio de cada línea.

Comment: Hola gracias lo tendré en cuenta para la proxìma, soy nuevo en stackoverflow como puede ver.. también puede ver que tengo un poco de problema con la ortografia pero mi teclado es en Italiano y se me complica un poco pero igual tratare de usar algùn corrector saludos